# Post vs. commit in PL SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I am just beginning to learn PL SQL Developer. I created a simple database schema and am adding a row into one of the tables. When I hover with the mouse over the "V" button, it shows "Post changes". When I click on that button and then issue `rollback`, the added row disappears. However, that does not happen if I issue `commit` prior to issuing `rollback`. What is the difference between `Post` and `Commit` and how do I commit using the GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Post` means *execute some inserts, updates and deletes corresponding to the changes made into the grid, and don't commit them*. `Commit` means *execute commit to save previously executed DMLs, both posted and/or executed directly into the current session*.

The simpliest way to commit in the PL/SQL Developer is to press `F10` button (using standart key configuration). You can also use *Session / Commit* item of the main menu, button in the toolbar and so on.

Answer (score 1):

POST is a way of temporarily saving changes to some buffer in PL/SQL Developer. The changes are not persisted to the database, so a ROLLBACK will undo them.

COMMIT is a SQL `commit` which applies the changes permanently to the database, so a ROLLBACK will have no affect.